# How to pass value from Activity to Page Adapter

Tags: android

i am quiet new to android. please help me out with this doubt.

i have created a image slider.
and i have an API i want to load the images from those API into slider.

i have created a Activity file.

```
public class MoreImage extends Activity {


    ImageView ProductImage;
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    UserFunctions userFunction;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    JSONObject jsonobject,jsonobj1;
    JSONObject jsonobj_prodPriceDetails, jsonobj_RUPEE;
    HListView listView;
    Button img_buy_now;



    String Vendor_id=null;

    SharedPreferences pref;
    String  Store_id_pref=null;
    String item_id_pref=null;
    EditText edt_search;
    public static Typeface font;
    String from=null;
    RelativeLayout  pb_progress;

    GridView related_grid;
    ImageView add_cart;
    String full_path_re;
    static TextView notifCount;

    ListView list;

    SrollviewAdapter scrAdapter;
    JSONArray jsonarray = null;
    JSONArray jsonarray1=null;
    JSONArray json_store_array = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> store_arraylist;
    String images;


    static String PRODUCT_IMAGES = "image_list";
    static String COUNT = "count";
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




          setContentView(R.layout.image_item);






          userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            new DownloadJSON().execute();



            pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
            Vendor_id=pref.getString("user_id", null); 
            Store_id_pref=pref.getString("store_id", null); 
            item_id_pref = pref.getString("item_id", null);

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            setTitle("Product List");
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
            from = myIntent.getStringExtra("from"); 

            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/Amaranth-Regular.otf");
            if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            } 

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        } 
        public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                //pb_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                jsonobject = userFunction.imageG("9");


                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("image_gallery");

                    jsonarray1 =jsonobj1.getJSONArray("count");

                    String s= jsonarray1.toString();

                    System.out.print("jsonarray1:::::"+jsonarray1);

                    int b= Integer.parseInt(s);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);



                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                      map.put("image_list", jsonobject.getString("image_list"));

                      map.put("count","jsonarray1");

                        arraylist.add(map);
                        System.out.print("all data::::::"+map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
                PagerAdapter adapter = new MoreImageAdapter(MoreImage.this);
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


                //pb_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }

        }



}
```

and this is a page adapter file

```
public class MoreImageAdapter  extends PagerAdapter{
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
   Context context;
    int count1;





//   int[] imageId = {
//         R.drawable.slide1,
//           R.drawable.slide2,
//           R.drawable.unfollow,
//           R.drawable.facebook_icon,
//           R.drawable.ic_launcher,
//           R.drawable.follow_unfollow,};

   public MoreImageAdapter(Context context){
       this.context = context;

   }


   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

       View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, container, false);
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);


       ((ViewPager)container).addView(viewItem);

       return viewItem;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return imageId.length;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       return view == ((View)object);
   }


   @Override
   public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
   }


}
```

there are two json objects one is image and other is count. image contains more then 1 image.

i am able to get the data from json parsing in activity class but i want to set the data in page adapter class as that shows my slider.

so how can i pass those value i got in activity file to page adapter class???

please help......

Comment: add your pager adapter with same activity..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those values using the constructor.

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new MoreImageAdapter(MoreImage.this, String images, ArrayList<Sting> something,...);
```

then in the MoreImageAdapter get those images from constructor

```
public MoreImageAdapter(Context context, String images, ArrayList<String> something,...){
   this.context = context;
   this.images = images;
   this.something = new ArrayList<String>(something);
}
```

You can send what all you want to send and get it from the constructor.